# How to get the "center" of grayscale numpy image

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array `arr` of shape `(m,n)` with nonnegative values. I would like to find a pair `(k,l)` such that

- the difference between `sum(arr[:k, :])` and `sum(arr[k:, :])` is minimal
- similarly, the difference between `sum(arr[:, :l])` and `sum(arr[:, l:])` is minimal

If you can come up with an algorithm only for `k`, the rest is actually easy. We simply transpose the matrix to find `l`.

**A note for the skeptical:** We may assume that `sum(arr[:k, :])` and `sum(arr[:,:l])` are *strictly* increasing functions of `k` and `l`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
sum_to_k = np.pad(np.cumsum(np.sum(a, axis=1)), (1, 0))
sum_to_l = np.pad(np.cumsum(np.sum(a, axis=0)), (1, 0))
k = np.argmin(np.abs(sum_to_k - (sum_to_k[-1] - sum_to_k)))
l = np.argmin(np.abs(sum_to_l - (sum_to_l[-1] - sum_to_l)))
```